# How rename description of Stripe subscription invoice line item from "trial period"

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I have a plan for which I generate subscriptions with trial periods.

Stripe is generating invoices with a *line item* of 0$ for this trial period, with **Trial period for <my_plan_name>** as *description*. I would like to rename this description because my customers are French (and you know, we French people don't speak very well English but that's another story).

When I'm trying to update the item description

```ruby
Stripe::InvoiceItem.update("sli_xyz",
                           { description: "Essai..." })
```

I'm getting error `Stripe::InvalidRequestError: When passing an invoice's line item id, you may only update tax_rates.`

I can't delete such a line item neither because this is a subscription item and I can't remove the description neither.

What am I missing here ? Is there a way to resolve that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two Stripe concepts here: an `Invoice` and `InvoiceItem`.

`InvoiceItem`s are essentially line items of individual items/services that is being tendered. An `Invoice` can contain many `InvoiceItem`s. Imagine an `Invoice` is the complete receipt, and `InvoiceItem` is the individual grocery item.

Normally, you can update the `InvoiceItem` either before you attach to an `Invoice`, or even after you attach it, before the `Invoice` is finalized/closed (a.k.a. paid for by the customer).

Stripe does not allow you to update the `description` of `InvoiceItem`s that are closed/finalized, because as a merchant, invoice is a record of what you sold (and receipting) to the customer, and once the invoice paid by the customer, you cannot change it.

Imagine if your invoice was originally for 50 beers, but after they pay for it, you decide to update the invoice to say 5 beers! How is that fair to your customers?

Your only solution is to make sure the `description` is defined properly in French for your French customers before issuing the invoice going forward into the future.

There is no way to fix this for past `InvoiceItem`s.

Comment: Yes I understand that some important invoice fields can not be edited after the payment. The problem here is that the invoice is automatically paid by Stripe because the amount is 0$, because of trialing.

Comment: Are there any updates for this. I'm facing the same issues when subscription changes from trial to paid plan. The invoice is created and stripe attempt to pay it in the subscription update, so we cannot edit invoice lines description :(